# How to hide the Post comments in the yammer feed

Tags: sharepoint-2013, yammer

One the client requested to hide the Yammer post comments box in the yammer embed feed section on few pages. Since it is iframe we were not able to handle using CSS.

We have tried yammer event with JS to hide. But it didn't worked.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: <div id="embedded-feed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script>
yam.connect.embedFeed({
container: "#embedded-feed",
feedType: "open-graph",
config: {
   header: false,
   footer: false
}
});
function hideMe() {
   $(".publisher-fake").hide();
   //$("iframe").contents().find(".publisher-fake").hide();
}
var yamObj = "";
yam.on('/embed/feed/loadingCompleted', hideMe, yamObj); </script>

Answer (score 0):

There is not a supported way to achieve this using Yammer Embed. As you noted the content is served within an iframe.

If the requirements are to not sure a publisher you could always use supported endpoints here (https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits) and try and build a feed using the messages api.

Good luck!